# Read multiple files under different directories in R

Tags: r, readfile

I have multiple files which have similar names under different directories. The directory are named similarly for example: dir1 -> dir10.

Under each directory there are files named f1 - f10, and I want to read the first file in each directory.

Could I use a read.csv for example? as I need to use a variable to represent both the directory and file names.

Comment: When you say "first file", do you mean it is always called f1?

Comment: The answer is certainly "yes," as you can specify directory and filename in `read.csv` . Are you looking for a script which turns, say "dir" and "1:10"  into "dir1, dir2, ...dir10"  and then passes those values as arguments to `read.csv` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An alternative for construction of file names is `sprintf`

```
file.paths <- sprintf ('dir%i/f1.csv', 1:10)
```

with `expand.grid`:

```
grid <- expand.grid (1:4, 1:3)
file.paths <- sprintf ('dir%i/f%i.csv', grid [[1]], grid [[2]])
```

Or, use `Sys.glob`

```
file.paths <- Sys.glob ('dir*/f1.csv')
```

the latter would also allow reading all f*.csv files in those dir*:

```
file.paths <- Sys.glob ('dir*/*f*.csv')
```

Answer (score 2):

If David was right with his question, and assuming your working directory is the dir containing all your sub directories...

```
file.paths <- paste0('dir', 1:10, '/', 'f1.csv')
lapply(file.paths, read.csv)
```

Should be easy enough to extend this example to your specific situation.  The only other function you might want to explore is `expand.grid` if you've got 10 files in each of 10 folders:

```
combos <- expand.grid(1:10, 1:10)
file.paths <- paste0('dir', combos[,1], '/f', combos[,2], '.csv')
```

Comment: you were faster... and you did write the `lapply` command that I omitted.